# JPA and DAO implementation of delete operation

Tags: java, jpa, dao

I'd like to know which implementation of the remove method is better:

```
public void remove(T t) {
   entityManager.remove(entityManager.merge(t));
}

public void remove(PK pk) {
   entityManager.remove(entityManager.getReference(entityType, pk));
}
```

I've read quite a lot of articles about this and in almost every one of them it's similar to the first approach, which appears to me quite needless since it can be done without the need to retrieve the whole entity from the database (if it's not present in the persistence context) and then remove it. Is there something I am missing and the first approach is really better ?

Comment: Why don't you call `entityManager.remove(t)` ?

Comment: @stacker: I want this method to remove both managed and detached entities.

Answer (score 1):

You could check whether the entity is managed by invoking

```
boolean isManaged = entityManager.contains( t );
```

If true simply call

```
entityManager.remove(t);
```

otherwise your second approach seems better since merging could cause more db activity due to eager loading (if configured). The javadoc on [getReference](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html)  says "Get an instance, whose state may be lazily fetched. If the requested instance does not exist in the database, throws EntityNotFoundException when the instance state is first accessed. (The persistence provider runtime is permitted to throw EntityNotFoundException when getReference(java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object) is called.) The application should not expect that the instance state will be available upon detachment, unless it was accessed by the application while the entity manager was open."

In short the entity has to be managed therfore, I would suggest:

```
em.remove(em.contains(r) ? r : em.merge(r));
```

Comment: This solution seems good, however, I'd be interested to know has anyone done any measuring if executing a JPQL/HQL-query along the lines of "DELETE FROM Entity e WHERE e.id=:id" would be faster than calling merge and then remove, when the entity is not contained in the manager? Does the overhead of building a query outweight not needing to fetch the entity?

Comment: It seems unnecessary to me, if the entity is present in the persistence context, invoking em.merge(r) returns the reference to the managed entity. That's not what this question is about. What bothers me is when the entity is not present in the persistence context.. because then the merge method must retrieve the entity from the database, which in this case seems to me unnecessary since I only need to remove a row from the database.